# Autowired doesn't work?

Tags: xml, spring, autowired

(Java Spring WebApp)

I have:

```
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

private PersonDAO d;

@Autowired
public void setD(PersonDAO d) {
    this.d = d;
}
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
\\ some logic
d.emailAlreadyExists("testMail@test.test"); 
}}
```

I thought I really understand beans and autowiring - seems not. "d.email.." code throws me null pointer exception and it does it really with any method of PersonDAO d. As I understand the problem is that nothing is injected.

However if I try to inject it on my controller which uses this Validator everything works:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController
{


private PersonDAO d;

@Autowired
public void setD(PersonDAO d) {
    this.d = d;
}

 // some method with RequestMapping declaration {
    Boolean b = d.emailAlreadyExists(person.getMail());       
logger.info( b.toString());

  // } end some method
```

Though this code above is not what I want.
I want to inject my DAO into PersonValidator as some of DAO's methods are need to do check against db. So that it would work following way:

```
 \\ these lines are in Controller under method
PersonValidator validator = new PersonValidator(); // my  d.emailAlreadyExists("testMail@test.test"); is inside
validator.validate(person, bindingResult);
```

PersonDAO is declared in xml, but PersonValidator is not. Can't I inject Spring DAO bean into simple java object such as PersonValidator which is not delcared in xml?

(component scanning is alright by the way - just in case)

Comment: Objects you want Spring beans injected  in to must be known to Spring via either XML or annotations, otherwise its lifecycle is completely independent of Spring.

Comment: But then they become invisible in the code itself. Sometimes it is not what I want. How would I use validator for person returned by form(I can't place that person in xml too since it is not singleton nature)l? Using .getBean and calling AppContext explicitly is not what I want to do..

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you're doing component scanning on the package in which `PersonValidator` is contained, it's sufficient to add the `@Component` annotation on top of `PersonValidator` class:

```
@Component
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {
```

Depending on your needs you may also want to change the singleton default scope:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {
```

Alternatively you can declare your `PersonValidator` in Spring XML. If you don't do one of these two things Spring won't even consider your Object and so nothing will get autowired in it.

Comment: I've declared as you suggested, but gives me exception that can't obtain connection. (Could not get JDBC Connection) Same does not happen with Controller though..(Controller can access db) DAO is wired well with dataSource, I am desperate

Comment: that is a different problem though, your question is about the NullPointer exception because you couldn't autowire the field, so is this first problem solved now?

Comment: it is not, because same injection works with Controller (works with DB perfectly and extracts what is needed). The problem seems to be that it is difficult to "autowire bean that already autowires another bean" in this case from Controller I try to autowire PersonValidator and this autowired validator has to autowire DAO - but something goes wrong. I just found solution but it's weird if I inject both DAO and PersonValidator into controller, PersonValidator's DAO injected inside suddenly starts to work. I am confused and question is OPEN.

Comment: one thing I notice re-reading your code is that you do `\\ these lines are in Controller under method PersonValidator validator = new PersonValidator();` -- don't do that. If you create your bean with new Spring will not autowire it (unless is @Configurable, but that's another story).

Comment: I removed that line of course. I don't know what really happens with the project, but on every second apache server re-run I get error of obtaining jdbc connection - sometimes work, sometimes not :-\ I guess you are right I accept your answer.